# Replacing wildcard in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, replace

I'm using this for replacing texts in a table in MySQL

```
UPDATE `nametable` SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'XoldtextX','XnewtextX');
```

But i don't know if it's possible to use wildcards for using this replacement function.

I have some texts like:

```
class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4071"

class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1762"

class="alignnone size-full wp-image-8329"
```

that i would like to change.

But i don't know how to make a rule for managing wildcards, as i would like to change the text whatever the number is it. Something like this:

```
class="alignnone size-full wp-image-XXXX"
```

Don't know if i can use something like this with the replace function, or do i have to do anyhting different in MySQL.

Thanks.

Comment: -what are you trying to replace with what exactly.?

Comment: What i want to do exactly is delete these lines, so i need to find a text and replace it in blank. I need to find class="alignnone size-full wp-image-XXXX" (there will be different numbers in all table), So i need a wildcard for XXXX

Comment: Maybe https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ is useful for you here?

Comment: Do't know if "Database Search and Replace" accept wildcards. Maybe a text editor can work too if it exists.

Comment: And what is your problem with given answers. There is no wildcards in SQL for this.

Comment: That is niot what i mean  When all thet text look like " some te3xt class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4071 even more text"  and you want  to replace exactly class="alignnone size-full wp-image-  with something new REPLACe can help you but with different  text is is alomost nit possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are no wildcards in the MySQL `REPLACE` function.

Introduced in MySQL 8.0 is `REGEXP_REPLACE` function. (Not available in earlier versions.)

Reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you want to change all texts. You can change numbers also with same technique, and specific text and numbers by adding where clause. You can change LEFT into RIGHT or use [SUBSTRING](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_mysql_substring.asp). See [CONCAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp) and [RIGHT](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_mysql_right.asp) used in this example. 
What ever suits your data. 
Example below is made for data provided in question.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
    INSERT INTO nametable (post_content) VALUES 
    ("alignnone size-full wp-image-4071"), 
    ("alignnone size-full wp-image-1762"), 
    ("alignnone size-full wp-image-8329"),  
    ("alignnone size-full wp-image-9837"), 
    ("something-else-9832"),
    ("alignnone NOT wp-image-9943"); 


    UPDATE nametable SET post_content = CONCAT("blank-",RIGHT(post_content,4));

---

**Query #1**

    SELECT * FROM nametable;

| id  | post_content |
| --- | ------------ |
| 1   | blank-4071   |
| 2   | blank-1762   |
| 3   | blank-8329   |
| 4   | blank-9837   |
| 5   | blank-9832   |
| 6   | blank-9943   |

---
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/22B4Uf9yXgXQV7sqKWzyjS/6)